# GLUT displays blank window

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

I'm following the [GLUT tutorial here](http://mindfuck.de-brauwer.be/articles/glut/).  I copy and pasted the first example "YAT" into xcode, slightly modified the includes and found that a blank window is brought up.  Unmodified the code is set to display a wireframe teapot.  For me, this does not happen.

However, if I uncomment the creation of a wire taurus, part of a taurus and the teapot appear in the window.  There are also seemingly random combinations of uncommenting and commenting lines under //draw something in the code that will actually cause objects to appear... or just a blank screen.

P.S. I know everyone says not to use GLUT but the graphics I will need for my final demo are very basic and everything else I've looked at has felt over my head.

Comment: Since when does GLUT include the model of a bull? A taurus is a male bovine, i.e. a bull. I think you meant a *torus*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I copy and pasted the first example "YAT" into xcode

The problem with this example is, that it doesn't request a double buffer, which however doesn't roll very well with MacOS X. It can be done, but there's no sense in actually doing it.

Replace `GLUT_SINGLE` with  `GLUT_DOUBLE` in the `glutInitDisplayMode` flags, i.e.

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
```

and add a `glutSwapBuffers()` at the end of the display function.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately I still don't have sufficient reputation to upvote you, but other people should.  I see now that the subsequent examples use double buffers... and thus work straight out of the can.